# Returning an Array using a function

Tags: arrays, function, conditional-statements

```
var experiences =[3,8,10,5,6,15,7,27];


function salary (experience)
{
    var salaries =[];
    for(var i =0;i<experience.length;i++)
    {
        if(experience[i]<5)
        {
            salaries.push=(experience[i]*10000);
        }
     else if(experience[i]>=5 && experience[i]<10)
    {
        salaries.push=(experience[i]*12000); 
    }
    else if(experience[i]>=10 && experience[i]<20)
    {
        salaries.push=(experience[i]*15000);
    }
    else
    {
        salaries.push=(experience[i]*20); 
    }
    return salaries;
}  

 }
var salaries= salary(experiences);
console.log(salaries);
```

1.I have used conditional statement here
2.function is returning an empty array.
3.Where am I wrong?
3.can anyone explain ,please?

Comment: What language is this? JavaScript?  If so the problem is that you have `salaries.push=` several times instead of `salaries.push`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Push. Just rewrite the existing value with a new one!
I hope I have been helpful.

```js
var experiences = [3, 8, 10, 5, 6, 15, 7, 27];

function salary(experiences) {
    var cloneArray = [...experiences]; // <- Clone Array
    for (var i = 0; i < cloneArray.length; i++) {
        if (cloneArray[i] < 5) {
            cloneArray[i] = (cloneArray[i] * 10000);
        }
        else if (cloneArray[i] < 10) {
            cloneArray[i] = (cloneArray[i] * 12000);
        }
        else if (cloneArray[i] < 20) {
            cloneArray[i] = (cloneArray[i] * 15000);
        }
        else {
            cloneArray[i] = (cloneArray[i] * 20);
        }
    }

    return cloneArray;
}

var salaries = salary(experiences);
console.log(salaries); // <- The result is in the cloned array

console.log(experiences); // <- The original array has not been changed
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you have `salaries.push=` in several places where you should have `salaries.push`.  What your code was doing before was reassigning the `push` built in method to be a number, rather than invoking `push`.  JavaScript is flexible that way but it's not what you want.

You can fix your code easily, but since you have a 1 to 1 mapping, it's an ideal candidate for the built-in [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.  Here's a solution using `map`.  Note: I think you wanted 20000, not 20, in the last case.

```js
var experiences = [3, 8, 10, 5, 6, 15, 7, 27];

function salary(experiences) {
    return experiences.map(experience => {
        if (experience < 5) {
            return experience * 10000;
        }
        if (experience < 10) {
            return experience * 12000;
        }
        if (experience < 20) {
            return experience * 15000;
        }
        return experience * 20000;
    });
}

var salaries = salary(experiences);
console.log(salaries);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.                                                                  I have not reached to  mapping topic but have learned something new earlier.So again thanks a lot and yeah that was 20000.